# Help with CSS Horizontal drop down menu

Tags: css, css-float

Hey guys, need some guidance on how to get the sub menu to drop directly under the whole width of the navigation bar for each and every option. Basically i want the sub menu to appear in one static position regardless of which option I hover over.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<link href="p7exp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="p7exp.js"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style>
#menuwrapper, #p7menubar ul a {height: 1%;}
a:active {width: auto;}
</style>
<![endif]-->

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>PVII CSS Express Drop-Down Menu</title>

</head>
<body onLoad="P7_ExpMenu()">
<div id="menuwrapper">
<ul id="p7menubar">
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/nav/nav_services_off.gif" width="74" height="74"  alt="Services" class="space" /></a></li>
<li><a class="trigger" href="#"><img src="images/nav/nav_services_off.gif" width="74" height="74"  alt="Services" class="space"/></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Sub 1.1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 1.2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 1.3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 1.4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a class="trigger" href="#"><img src="images/nav/nav_services_off.gif" width="74" height="74"  alt="Services" class="space"/></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Sub 2.1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 2.2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 2.3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 2.4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 2.5</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a class="trigger" href="#"><img src="images/nav/nav_services_off.gif" width="74" height="74"  alt="Services" class="space"/></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Sub 3.1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 3.2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 3.3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 3.4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 3.5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 3.6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 3.7</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub 3.8</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<br class="clearit">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS

```
#menuwrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    float:right;
    padding:0 5px 0 5px;

}

.space {
padding-left:2.5px;
padding-right:2.5px;
}

.clearit {
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0.0;
    font-size: 0;
}

#p7menubar, #p7menubar ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

img {
border:none;
}


#p7menubar li {
    float: left;
    width: 9em;
}

#p7menubar li ul, #p7menubar ul li  {
    width: 12em;
}



#p7menubar li ul {
    margin:-5px 0px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #434344;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width:300px;
}



#p7menubar li:hover a, #p7menubar a:focus,
#p7menubar a:active, #p7menubar li.p7hvr a {
    color: #000000;

}

#p7menubar li:hover ul, #p7menubar li.p7hvr ul {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#p7menubar ul a:hover {
    background-color: #434344!important;
    color: #FFFFFF!important;

#p7menubar li {width: auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

possibly add position:relative; to the #menuwrapper style, and set left:0; top 20px; for the li ul, replacing "20px" with the height of the menu (couldn't see this value anywhere)